# Android: Not able to access storage to save image

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have an imageview which is loaded using a url. 
I want to download the image in the view and store it in internal/external drive of mobile. But i tried all possible method on Stackoverflow couldn't access the drive even with the premission given on the mobile to access read and write in the external memory. Nothing seems to work i don't know why?

This is my Code, can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

    File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "test.png");
    boolean success = false;

    // Encode the file as a PNG image.
    FileOutputStream outStream;
    try {

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        success = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (success) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Manifest permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Without giving information on what exactly is failing we can't solve the problem.

Comment: @HoboJoe I'm getting "error during image saving"

Comment: Is this on an API > 23 device? If so, you need to ask for permission at runtime. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html. Putting permissions in the manifest is only enough pre-23.

Comment: @HoboJoe no, I tried on API 19 too. I got the same error.

Comment: `"error during image saving" ` A nonsense answer! That is your own toast! Which you display when `success== false`. Now if success is not made true then what happened before? Place toasts there which display e.getMessage().

Comment: You should have posted the logcat too.

Comment: add permission at runtime of version greater than 23 else not

Comment: @ShivamOberoi I have tried this on API 19 simulator still it doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 0):

```
File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getDataDirectory();
```

That is not the sd card directory.

```
Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() == /data
```

You have no write permission there. Better use

```
File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

That will work if you got your permissions right.

But it will not save to the SD card!

Comment: Hey, I want to save anywhere possible. Either external storage or the internal storage. I first tried the external storage directory it didn't work hence went with internal storage.. both doesn't seem to work.

Comment: External storage should work if you have the runtime permissions right. Which errors exceptions do you get? Try again!  Dont give up.